System.Text.Json ecapes single quotes by design
I know that System.Text.Json escapes single quotes by design, but the examples for how to allow certain characters to not be escaped from MS Docs doesn't work for me as I want to keep single quotes in my serialized JSON.
var encoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
encoderSettings.AllowCharacters('\u0027', '\'');
encoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin);
var encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Create(encoderSettings);
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = encoder,
};

var bodyJSON = JsonSerializer.Serialize(eventToSend, options);

Is the easy solution to switch to NewtonSoft instead as it is much more user-friendly and by default keeps the single quotes? I have nothing but convoluted trouble and googling for configurations when using System.Text.Json

Whether you should use a different package is an opinion, only you can decide if it’s right for you, taking into account your specific circumstances.
